# Equality between derivatives of the metric

Tags: differential-geometry, symmetry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, geodesics

In one of my lecture, it is said:

> Let us use the freedom of the choice of parametrization to demand that the variation of $\lambda$ after a small displacement along the curve is proportional to the length of the displacement. Such parameter $\lambda$ is called *affine*. One has thus
>   $$
> d\lambda^2 = K\,g_{ab}\,dx^a dx^b \quad (\mbox{with $K$ constant})\;\rightarrow\;g_{ab}{x'}^a{x'}^b = K^{-1}
> $$
>
> The previous equation is then reduced to
>   $$
> \boxed{
> \frac{d}{d\lambda}(g_{ac}{x'}^a) = \tfrac12 {x'}^a{x'}^b \,\partial_cg_{ab}
> }$$
>
> This is the first form of the equations of the *geodesic curves*, or curve of extremal length, in the *affine parametrization*.
>
> Remark $\rightarrow$ For such a definition of geodesics to make sense, it is necessary that a metric exists (only case considered here), and it has to be positive definite.
>
> The geodesic equation can take another form by expanding the left hand side:
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> g_{ac}{x''}^a + &\underbrace{\frac{dg_{ac}}{d\lambda} {x'}^a} = \tfrac12 {x'}^a {x'}^b \,\partial_c g_{ab}\\
> &=\partial_b g_{ac}\frac{dx^b}{d\lambda} {x'}^a = {x'}^a{x'}^b \partial_b g_{ac} = \tfrac12 (\partial_a g_{bc} + \partial_c g_{ac}){x'}^a{x'}^b
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>   $$
> g_{ac}{x''}^a+\tfrac12(\partial_a g_{bc} + \partial_c g_{ac}-\partial_cg_{ab}){x'}^a{x'}^b = 0
> $$
>   multiply by $g^{cd}$
>   $$
> \boxed{
> {x''}^d + \tfrac12 g^{cd}(\partial_a g_{bc} + \partial_c g_{ac}-\partial_cg_{ab}) {x'}^a{x'}^b = 0
> }
> $$

How to prove at the bottom of page that:

$$x'^{a}\,x'^{b}\,\partial_{b}g_{ac} = \dfrac{1}{2}(\partial_{a}g_{bc}+\partial_{b}g_{ac})\,x'^{a}\,x'^{b}$$

that would imply that: $\partial_{b}g_{ac}=\partial_{a}g_{bc}$ , is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps
$
x^a x^b \partial_b g_{ac} =\\
=1/2\cdot x^a x^b \partial_b g_{ac}+1/2\cdot x^a x^b \partial_b g_{ac}\\
=1/2\cdot x^a x^b \partial_b g_{ac}+1/2\cdot x^b x^a \partial_b g_{ac}\\
=1/2\cdot x^a x^b \partial_b g_{ac}+1/2\cdot x^a x^b \partial_a g_{bc}
$

I am not entirely confident that substitutions are allowed on subformulas like that but if they are this seems to do the trick.

So the answer is for most instances no; the equality is for the fully contracted term, not the partial derivatives of the tensor components in isolation.

Comment: thanks a lot ! that was the trick